# DropdownSearch Flutter - Font too big

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, dropdown, responsive

I have the following code for the dropdownSearch in Flutter
However, the font is fixed and does not change when I change the screen size

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUyjR.png)

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
        items: items,
        showSearchBox: showSearchBox ?? false,
        dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
          floatingLabelStyle:
              kResponsiveTextUbuntuFont(context, kDarkGreyColor),
          labelText: labelTxt,
          labelStyle: kResponsiveTextUbuntuFont(context, kDarkGreyColor),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kDarkGreyColor, width: 2),
          ),
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kDarkGreyColor, width: 2),
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: (newItem) => {},
        showSelectedItems: true,
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        popupBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        dropdownSearchBaseStyle:
            kResponsiveTextUbuntuFont(context, kDarkGreyColor),
        mode: Mode.MENU,
      ),
```

Font:

```
TextStyle KResponsiveTitleUbuntuFont(BuildContext context, Color color) {
  return TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
      fontSize:
          (setWidth(context, 0.001) >= 1) ? 30 * setWidth(context, 0.001) : 50,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
      wordSpacing: 5,
      color: color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find the solution directly after asking my own question xD...
Here's the solution:

```
  Widget _customDropDownText(BuildContext context, String? name) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        name.toString(),
        style: kResponsiveTextUbuntuFont(context, kDarkGreyColor),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Build:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.
.
.
DropdownSearch<String>(
        items: widget.items,
        dropdownBuilder: _customDropDownText,
        showSearchBox: widget.showSearchBox ?? false,
.
.
.
}
```

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82BAT.png)